# How to call outer classes functions with the same name as the calling inner class function

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading, inner-classes

Title says it all. Suppose I have this:

```
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        void a(int i) {
            Outer::a(i); // Error: Illegal of non-static member function
        }
    };

    void a(int i) {}
};
```

How would that `Inner::a` declaration be?

Comment: Define function a in struct Outer as static and also get a instance from struct Inner in Outer Struct.

Comment: What about dong this:

struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        static std::function<void(int)> fn;
    };
    void a(int i) {}
};

std::function<void(int)> Outer::Inner::fn = std::bind(
    &Outer::a, std::move(std::make_shared<Outer>(new Outer).get()), _1);

Comment: Henri, I think I answered your question. However, I don't think that you're asking the right question. What is the behavior you're trying to create? Why have a nested class at all? Take a step back and ask yourself what your goal is. That would possibly allow you to ask a better question that really helps you. See also "XY Problem".

Comment: Does it help to tell you to act as if an inner class is basically a different class with an additional suffix? That is, to treat them as if you have two separate structures `Outer` and `OuterInner`? The line `Outer::a(i);` is the same as if you would call it in a function, like `void foo(int i) { Outer::a(i); }`. As there is no object present and `a` is not static, there is nothing to call `a` from.

Comment: But as Ulrich already said, really sounds like a XY problem. I'd strongly recommend that you give us your context to work with.

Comment: This is no XY problem. Thats what im currently struggling with and definitely would solve it if it worked. Static functions are not what im looking for and it worked using internal `Outer` pointers, but this is not exactly what im looking for. I thought we could call any Outer function within Inner, even if they had same names (and in this case we should use qualified names instead, just like in inheritances/overrides). The class structure cant be changed.

Comment: A pointer is equivalent to a reference, it gives you an `Outer` instance to call functions on. There is no instance in your code, so that's what you need first. A function is something different than a memberfunction. Also, you can access any memberfunction from the outer scope, which is necessary but not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way. There isn't even a fixed relation between outer and inner class (like aggregation), you could create inner instances without outer instances and vice versa.

BTW: The fact that the two memberfunctions are both called `a` is totally irrelevant here.

Comment: If inner is aware of outer (even private stuff), why cant it call the function through it's qualified name?!

Comment: In order to call a memberfunction, you need an instance. You don't have one, so you can't. If you had an `Outer& o` accessible inside `Outer::Inner::a()`, you could call `o.a()`.

Comment: I'll answer your comment here. The reasons for inner classes I found is to create a fluent API. It's a personal decision I found better to suit my needs. They were unested classes at some point, but then I was facing the cyclic dependency problem. Also, I had it working with internal `Outer` pointers, but I thought it would be possible that way (qualified name), since I can call any `Outer` function within `Inner::a` (with different function names, other than `a`). If you're curious about the real code, I'll edit my question.

Comment: If you have working code, consider posting it on codereview.stackexchange.com. You could describe the way in which you would like to refactor and improve the code. Here, you show non-working code and ask for ways to fix it that are not possible.

Answer (score 0):

> *How to call outer classes functions with the same name as the calling inner class function?*

You must need to create an instance of the class before trying to access the member functions directly.

**Thus, there are two ways to do this:**

1. Declare the function signature with `static`.
2. Create an instance of the `Outer` and access the member function with a dot operator.

---

**Example 1:**

```
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        void a(int i) {
            Outer::a(i); // direct member function access
        }
    };

    static void a(int i) { // declared as static
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Outer::Inner in;

    in.a(10); // Inner class calls the member of Outer class's a(int)

    return 0;
}
```

**Example 2:**

```
struct Outer {
    struct Inner {
        void a(int i) {
            Outer x;    // instance to the class Outer
            x.a(i);     // accessing the member function
        }
    };

    void a(int i) {     // outer class definition
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Outer::Inner in; // creating an instance of Inner class

    in.a(10); // accessing the Inner member function (which accesses
              // Outer class member function)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you came from java, the declaration in C++

```
class Outer { 
  class Inner {
  };
};
```

means in java:

```
 class A {
   static class B {   // <- static class
   };
 };
```

all inner classes in c++ are kinda "equivalent" to `static` inner classes in java